# Is there a way to update selected row data on a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

- I am trying to change data of a selected row. In my case when a row is clicked it returns the index of that row and then i am trying to update that row with the index of the row i clicked. I can get the index properly, but when i try to update the row it gives an error "Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0,column 0".
- In this case the index that i am trying to update is 0. Here is my code

  var newdata=['data','data2','data2','data4'];

  table.row(0).data(newdata).draw()

Comment: You mean need to update the value by cell right?

Comment: Yes i am trying to update every cell of the selected row in this case the selected row index is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you!

```
var dtable= $('#example').DataTable();
rowId = 0 ; //first row
newData = [ "column1 data", "column2 data", "column3 data" ] //Array, data here must match structure of table data
dtable.row(rowId).data( newData ).draw();
```